# Why transclusion scope is not sibling with directive scope?

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

This is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>            
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>          
</head>


<body>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <testel title="{{data.title}}">
        <input ng-model="data.title">
         <h3>Transclude title: {{title}}</h3>
         <h3>Transclude data title: {{data.title}}</h3>
    </testel>
</div>

 <script>

  angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.data={};
    $scope.data.title="Gas";
})
.directive('testel', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl:   "./transclude.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {         
           console.log(scope.$$nextSibling);
        }
    }    
}); 
 </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

and transclude.html:

```
<h3>Template title: {{title}}</h3>
<h3>Template data title:{{data.title}}</h3>
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
```

Why am I getting null from console.log(scope.$$nextSibling)? I was waiting the transclusion scope instead.

Also, how may I console.log the transclusion scope itself?

Comment: i guess it is child, not sibling

Comment: It is sibling definitely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Angular 1.3+ it is a child of isolated scope. Prior to that, they were siblings.